# Google charts, how to add custom points on Gantt Charts?

Tags: javascript, svg, charts, google-visualization, gantt-chart

I'm trying to add some custom points on a Gantt charts. But I don't see any official way to do that.
Any one know how I can make this ?

I tried to add some point like triangle below
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are no standard options to add custom points,
but we can manually add on the chart's `'ready'` event.

see following working snippet,
function `addMarker` will add a triangle to the chart.

pass arguments for row label and date for point placement, e.g.

```
addMarker('Find sources', new Date(2019, 0, 3));
addMarker('Outline paper', new Date(2019, 0, 5, 12));
addMarker('Write paper', new Date(2019, 0, 8));
```

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['gantt']
}).then(function () {
  var container = document.getElementById('gantt');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Gantt(container);

  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Task ID');
  dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Task Name');
  dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Resource');
  dataTable.addColumn('date', 'Start Date');
  dataTable.addColumn('date', 'End Date');
  dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Duration');
  dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Percent Complete');
  dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Dependencies');
  dataTable.addRows([
    ['Research', 'Find sources', null, new Date(2019, 0, 1), new Date(2019, 0, 5), null,  100,  null],
    ['Write', 'Write paper', 'write', null, new Date(2019, 0, 9), daysToMilliseconds(3), 25, 'Research,Outline'],
    ['Cite', 'Create bibliography', 'write', null, new Date(2019, 0, 7), daysToMilliseconds(1), 20, 'Research'],
    ['Complete', 'Hand in paper', 'complete', null, new Date(2019, 0, 10), daysToMilliseconds(1), 0, 'Cite,Write'],
    ['Outline', 'Outline paper', 'write', null, new Date(2019, 0, 6), daysToMilliseconds(1), 100, 'Research']
  ]);

  var dateRangeStart = dataTable.getColumnRange(3);
  var dateRangeEnd = dataTable.getColumnRange(4);
  var formatDate = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
    pattern: 'MM/dd/yyyy'
  });
  var rowHeight = 45;

  var options = {
    height: ((dataTable.getNumberOfRows() * rowHeight) + rowHeight),
    gantt: {
      criticalPathEnabled: true,
      criticalPathStyle: {
        stroke: '#e64a19',
        strokeWidth: 5
      }
    }
  };

  function daysToMilliseconds(days) {
    return days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  }

  function drawChart() {
    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
  }

  function addMarker(markerRow, markerDate) {
    var baseline;
    var baselineBounds;
    var chartElements;
    var marker;
    var markerSpan;
    var rowLabel;
    var svg;
    var svgNS;
    var gantt;
    var ganttUnit;
    var ganttWidth;
    var timespan;
    var xCoord;
    var yCoord;

    // initialize chart elements
    baseline = null;
    gantt = null;
    rowLabel = null;
    svg = null;
    svgNS = null;
    chartElements = container.getElementsByTagName('svg');
    if (chartElements.length > 0) {
      svg = chartElements[0];
      svgNS = svg.namespaceURI;
    }
    chartElements = container.getElementsByTagName('rect');
    if (chartElements.length > 0) {
      gantt = chartElements[0];
    }
    chartElements = container.getElementsByTagName('path');
    if (chartElements.length > 0) {
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(chartElements, function(path) {
        if ((baseline === null) && (path.getAttribute('fill') !== 'none')) {
          baseline = path;
        }
      });
    }
    chartElements = container.getElementsByTagName('text');
    if (chartElements.length > 0) {
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(chartElements, function(label) {
        if (label.textContent === markerRow) {
          rowLabel = label;
        }
      });
    }
    if ((svg === null) || (gantt === null) || (baseline === null) || (rowLabel === null) ||
        (markerDate.getTime() < dateRangeStart.min.getTime()) ||
        (markerDate.getTime() > dateRangeEnd.max.getTime())) {
      return;
    }

    // calculate placement
    ganttWidth = parseFloat(gantt.getAttribute('width'));
    baselineBounds = baseline.getBBox();
    timespan = dateRangeEnd.max.getTime() - dateRangeStart.min.getTime();
    ganttUnit = (ganttWidth - baselineBounds.x) / timespan;
    markerSpan = markerDate.getTime() - dateRangeStart.min.getTime();

    // add marker
    marker = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'polygon');
    marker.setAttribute('fill', 'transparent');
    marker.setAttribute('stroke', '#ffeb3b');
    marker.setAttribute('stroke-width', '3');
    xCoord = (baselineBounds.x + (ganttUnit * markerSpan) - 4);
    yCoord = parseFloat(rowLabel.getAttribute('y'));
    marker.setAttribute('points', xCoord + ',' + (yCoord - 10) + ' ' + (xCoord - 5) + ',' + yCoord + ' ' + (xCoord + 5) + ',' + yCoord);
    svg.insertBefore(marker, rowLabel.parentNode);
  }

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    // add marker for current date
    addMarker('Find sources', new Date(2019, 0, 3));
    addMarker('Outline paper', new Date(2019, 0, 5, 12));
    addMarker('Write paper', new Date(2019, 0, 8));
  });

  window.addEventListener('resize', drawChart, false);
  drawChart();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="gantt"></div>
```

---

**UPDATE**

the size of the marker is specified in the `'points'` attribute of the polygon element.
at the bottom of the `addMarker` function,
see the line for --> `marker.setAttribute('points', ...`

the value of `'points'` should be three sets of x,y coordinates.
top, left, & right respectively.
*note: adding four sets of x,y coordinates would add a rectangle marker.*

the variables `xCoord` & `yCoord` are the calculated x,y coordinates of where the marker should be placed, and should be the center of the marker.
as such, in order to draw the triangle...
top = `xCoord + ',' + (yCoord - 10)`
left = `(xCoord - 5) + ',' + yCoord`
right = `(xCoord + 5) + ',' + yCoord`

in summary, in order to change the size of the marker,
we change the modifiers made to the variables `xCoord` & `yCoord`

to reduce the size of the marker by half,
we would change the coordinates as follows...
top = `xCoord + ',' + (yCoord - 5)`
left = `(xCoord - 2.5) + ',' + yCoord`
right = `(xCoord + 2.5) + ',' + yCoord`

e.g.

```
marker.setAttribute('points', xCoord + ',' + (yCoord - 5) + ' ' + (xCoord - 2.5) + ',' + yCoord + ' ' + (xCoord + 2.5) + ',' + yCoord);
```

Comment: In the above example how can we decrease the size of the triangle(Marker) ?

Comment: @Thank you! It helped.